# Python .upper and .lower methods returning no results

Tags: python, methods, uppercase, lowercase

I'm having trouble getting Python's .upper and .lower methods to return anything.  Here's the code:

```
initials = input("Enter your initials: ")
uppercase = initials.upper
print(uppercase)
```

What it returns is:

```
Enter your initials: mj
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x7f50734b01f0>
```

I originally integrated this into a larger function, but when I call uppercase later in the function the variable remains empty.  I'm working in Google Colab.

Comment: It's because you didn't call it. try `initials.upper()`

Comment: Hint: why did you **not** write simply `initials = input`? Can you think of how to apply the same logic to the other *method* you want to use? Also, did you notice how what you get in the `print` result from the method says "method" in it? So it's printing the method itself, right? (Was that unclear?) Does that give you some idea of what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a method in Python, you must open and close parenthesis after the name of the method:

```
uppercase = initials.upper()
```

See the example in the documentations of [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just make sure you use .upper() method appropriately with your variable. :)

```
initials = input("Enter your initials: ")

print(initials.upper())
```